# Attempting to write a row[10] in the range [0,21] that is already written to disk

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I get data from DB and insert it into Excel File.
I have to methods of inserting this data: with using `var sxssfWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(workbook);` and without.
First method looks like this:

```java
@SneakyThrows
public String insertDataToExcelSheet(File fileCopy, Map<Reports, List<List<Object>>> reportsTablesMap) {
    try (var fis = new FileInputStream(fileCopy);
        var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        var sxssfWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(workbook);
        var fos = new FileOutputStream(fileCopy)) {

            try {
                reportsTablesMap.forEach(
                        (sheet, data) -> processBatch(sxssfWorkbook, sheet, data)
                );
                sxssfWorkbook.write(fos);
            } finally {
                // paranoid dispose.
                // If we run into error while process batch, then we
                // always dispose temporary files from streaming sxssf workbook
                sxssfWorkbook.dispose();
                currentRowCount = 0;
            }
        }
        return fileCopy.getName();
    }
}
```

Second one is similar, but without `var sxssfWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(workbook);`
When I use the first method I catch outOfMemory exception due to 2+ millions objects and with the second one I catch Attempting to write a row[10] in the range [0,21] that is already written to disk.

Here is the `processBatch`:

```
private void processBatch(Workbook workbook, Reports reportSheet, List<List<Object>> reportData) {
    Row row = null;
    Cell cell = null;
    CellStyle style = null;
    int startRow = reportSheet.getStartRow();
    int startColumn = reportSheet.getStartColumn();
    int maxRowsPerSheet = 1000000;
    String sheetName = reportSheet.getSheetName();
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
    style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
    log.info("Post to new paper '{}' started", sheetName);
    for (List<Object> report : reportData) {
        if (currentRowCount >= maxRowsPerSheet) {
            newSheetName = sheetName + "^" + (countActiveSheet + 1);
            log.info("Post to new paper '{}'", newSheetName);
            countActiveSheet++;
            sheet = workbook.createSheet(newSheetName);
            currentRowCount = 0;
            startColumn = 0;
            startRow = 0;
        }
        currentRowCount++;
        row = sheet.getRow(startRow);
        int columnCount = startColumn;
        if (row == null) {
            row = sheet.createRow(startRow);
        }
        for (Object field : report) {
            cell = row.getCell(columnCount);
            if (cell == null) {
                cell = row.createCell(columnCount);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
            }
            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case STRING: {
                    if (field == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (!((String) field).equalsIgnoreCase("formula"))
                        cell.setCellValue((String) field);
                    else
                        cell.setCellValue(cell.getCellFormula());
                }
                    break;
                case NUMERIC: {
                    if (field == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (field instanceof Integer)
                        cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
                    else if (field instanceof Long)
                        cell.setCellValue((Long) field);
                    else if (field instanceof Date)
                        cell.setCellValue((Date) field);
                    else
                        cell.setCellValue((Double) field);
                }
                    break;
                case BOOLEAN:
                    cell.setCellValue((Boolean) field);
                    break;
                case FORMULA: {
                }
                    break;
                case BLANK: {
                    if (field == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (field instanceof Double) {
                        cell.setCellValue((double) field);
                    }
                    else if (field instanceof Integer) {
                        cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
                    }
                    else if (field instanceof Long) {
                        cell.setCellValue((Long) field);
                    }
                    else if (field instanceof Boolean) {
                        cell.setCellValue((Boolean) field);
                    }
                    else if (field instanceof Date) {
                        cell.setCellValue((Date) field);
                    }
                    else if (field instanceof String
                            && !((String) field).equalsIgnoreCase("formula")) {
                        cell.setCellValue((String) field);
                    }
                }
                    break;
            }
            columnCount++;
        }
        startRow++;
    }
    log.info("Post to page '{}' finished", sheetName);
    reportData.clear();
}
```

I've tried to use methods with ignoring inserted blocks and also tried methods with checking excel file, but suddenly it didn't help me. Problem is that I can't clear the Excel file because it's protected, but in the blocks there are nothing.

Comment: [Edit] your question and post the entire stack trace of the error(s) you are getting.

Comment: Well, it is how it is. `XSSFWorkbook` needs much memory because it always needs to hold the whole `*.xlsx`-ZIP-File and additional all XML-objects in memory. And `SXSSFWorkbook` saves memory by writing handled row data into temporary files. But that means that all rows of all sheets need to be written top down in one step. Already written rows are not accessible later. So either you give the `XSSFWorkbook` enough memory ore you do using `SXSSFWorkbook` as it is made for.